# Group relations between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database where certain nodes can be related with up to 5 different relations. I am trying to do a large query in Cypher but there is way too much information duplicated, and I am having some memory errors.

Imagine the following picture:

[image: Nodes with multiple relations]

I get the results as:

```
(node1, r1, REL_A, node2)
(node1, r2, REL_B, node2)
(node1, r3, REL_C, node2)
(node1, r4, REL_D, node2)
(node1, r5, REL_E, node2)
```

The query I am using looks like this:

```
MATCH (n:NODE_TYPE_A)-[d:REL1|REL2|REL3|REL4|REL5]->(p) RETURN DISTINCT n,d,type(d),p
```

Is there a way to return `node1` and `node2` only once with an array of all the relations? That way the results would be way smaller and I could handle them much better without memory errors.

Comment: Did you try using distinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (n:NODE_TYPE_A)-[d:REL1|REL2|REL3|REL4|REL5]->(p) 
return n, collect(type(d)), p;
```

Comment: In your first approach, I still get the same output. Each pair of nodes and IDs is repeated for each relation. As for the second one, although it would be great, each relation has a property that I need to retrieve, so I need all of the relationships. That is why I asked if the relations could be grouped in an array or something similar.

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I need! Unfortunately I get this error: `Type mismatch: expected Collection<T> but was Relationship`.

Comment: Probably just an identifier error - works for me, try this simple sample case to make sure it's what you want.   DATA:  `CREATE (a:x {x:1}), (b:x {x:2}) MERGE (a)-[:r1 {y:1}]->(b) MERGE (a)-[:r2 {y:2}]->(b) MERGE (a)-[:r3 {y:3}]->(b);`

Comment: QUERY:  `MATCH (a:x {x:1})-[r*]->(b:x {x:2}) return a.x,b.x,collect(extract(item in r | item.y));`

Comment: Alright, updated answer again -- this time I got it.  I was missing lack of variable path length so you don't need to do the extract at all.  Just collect the types.